# How to determine if an assembly is in use?

Tags: assemblies

How can I tell if an assembly is in use by any process?

Comment: By any means? Or do you want to use a specific programming language?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer in PowerShell

```
if ( Get-Process | ? { $_.Modules | ? {$_.ModuleName -eq "AssemblyName.dll" } })
{
    "in use"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if your application has loaded the assembly, you can inspect the AppDomain for loaded assemblies. If you want to know if the assembly is loaded by *any* process on the machine, it gets a little bit trickier. Which of the above do you need ?